# Standard Property Dialog/Browser for ActiveX - Control

Tags: c++, activex

I am looking for a property browser/editor for generic activeX controls.

It must work for controls that just expose an IDispatch interface, no proeprty pages of their own.

Best would be something that comes with the OS (like the "All properties" property page VC6 used). It is only for testing, so comfort is not important, modal property sheet or embedded activeX control. The test application is an MFC project.

I *thought* there was something like that, but the best I can find right now is `OleCreatePropertyFrame` (which is only the dialog, but not the page i'm after)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [OLE-COM Obect Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=5233b70d-d9b2-4cb5-aeb6-45664be858b6&displaylang=en)?  It's included in the SDK or can be installed separately via this link.

Comment: something to embed in the test application